# Sprite Suffixes - Rebuilding game on sprite builder

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cross-platform, 2d-games, spritebuilder

I am trying to update an old game developed using Cocos Builder (which no longer is supported) i now want to build it for iPhone 5 and above. To update I have to rebuild my scenes using new Sprite Builder.

Previously we used to give suffixes for retina, e.g. spritename-hd.png, I am trying to do the same with sprite builder, I have two versions of each sprite, one with -hd and one without a suffix. But sprite builder doesn't use sprites with -hd for retina devices?

I am new to sprite builder how to fix it? So that my game works for all iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use image suffixes in SpriteBuilder at all.

SpriteBuilder converts the images to the various resolutions and places them in separate folders for specific devices. You just need to supply the images at the highest resolution - though SpriteBuilder will also scale images up that would mean a loss in image quality and is therefore not recommended.